# webgltexture, Where is Image object docs?

Tags: javascript, image, three.js, webgl

I've been searching for more than 2 hours, where is Image doc? what members do it have?
Ok, i know its existence from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Using_textures_in_WebGL

```
...
const pixel = new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]);  // opaque blue
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,
                width, height, border, srcFormat, srcType,
                pixel);

  const image = new Image(); // <---- here
  image.onload = () => {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,
                  srcFormat, srcType, image);
...
```

and here: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture

but both places say nothing about it, i don't know where it is located and what members and member functions do it have, anybody please help, thank you.

Comment: `Image` is not a webgl or three.js object. See [`Image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image)

Comment: Thank you. I googled 'javascript Image' after i post this and found the same thing, but i was not sure its the Image object that i expected, your answer confirmed it is, thank you.